# unable to get the files in server side

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a HTML form in `edit_cust.php` as below :

```
<form name="editcustomer" method="post" action="edit_cust.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fl4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1"/>

    <div class="supp_l"></div><div class="supp_r"><input type="submit" value="UPDATE" /></div>
</form>
```

And the PHP code :

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])){

    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

But the `var_dump` is not showing the `file`. The output is :

```
array
  'check' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Why it is not showing the files fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check using `$_FILES['check']`.

$_POST is not used for file upload. $_FILE is the variable used to handle file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILES['check']` instead of `$_POST['check']`